# Eclipse + CubeMX a fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: ubuntu, java, eclipse

Good evening! I am new to Linux and I'm trying to learn the Eclipse environment for STM32 microcontroller developing. I have installed Eclipse and trying to install a plugin to work with microcontrollers. The plugin installation is successful but when I click Window->Show view->Other->Cube MX it crashes with the following error:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f570faa92b7, pid=7360, tid=0x00007f57bfc5f700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0+0x4e2b7]  gdk_display_open+0x57
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f57b800b000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=7361, stack(0x00007f57bfb5f000,0x00007f57bfc60000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000114
```

I was trying to upgrade to Oracle Java, tried to enter the command "ulimit -c unlimited" to reinstall the plugin and Eclipse itself, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, and worked around it with the following actions:

1. Update eclipse.ini to make Eclipse use GTKv2:

   Add the lines:

   `--launcher.GTK_Version 2`

   making sure you add them to the Eclipse options and not the VM arguments contained in the file.
2. Run Eclipse as root